# How do I display a program from SUSE Ent. Server from my Ubuntu Desktop machine?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, linux

I am running a regular Ubuntu desktop machine running X-windows.  I am remoted into a SUSE 11 Enterprise Server  that doesn't have X installed.

My understanding is that even without X installed on the remote server, I should be able to run a windowed program from the remote SUSE server on my local desktop.

I'm connected using:
  ssh -i Cert.pem -X myuser@ip.add.re.ss

If this is posible, what do I type in the console to get the remote program displayed?

Also, when I type "xterm" it says "xterm: command not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are always certain libraries required to start an X11 program and when the administrator of the server didn't install them, you are out of luck. The fact that even xterm isn't working is a good indication that this is the case.

If you can install software on the SLES server, installing `xterm` should pull in the basic requirements to display a program over an SSH tunnel, but the software you want to use might need more.

Comment: thats what I thought.  thanks.  the machine doesn't have yast either and so I am not sure I want to attempt gathering all the required RPMs myself.

Answer (score 0):

You'll still need the install the X-based applications, such as xterm.

Here's a nice tutorial - http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html